# How does Joey Marks know which bank to go to in S2E8 "Follow The Money"?

Tags: plot-explanation, bosch

**Spoiler warning:** this question spoils most of the details of the main case in Season 2 of Bosch, specifically episodes 1-8. (It doesn't discuss eps. 9 or 10.)

---

In this episode, four groups of people converge at a single bank where some loot has been stashed. It ends up being a race, because only one of these people is legally permitted to access the loot, and that person doesn't obtain permission until that very morning (which event is effectively the "starting pistol" for this race). The rest of the folks go there either to take the loot after it has been withdrawn from the bank by its legal owner, or to seize said owner.

One of those groups is Joey Marks & his crew, but I can't figure out how they knew to be there.

The "race" sequence begins right around the 28-minute mark of ep. 8. In the order of their arrival at the bank, the groups are:

1. **Carl Nash & his crew**

   We see them *after* we see Veronica arrive, but they're already parked and lying in wait, and they spot her going in. Thus, they arrived first.
2. **Veronica Allen**

   She is the only person who has the right to withdraw the loot. A court grants that right this very morning, and she presumably goes directly to the bank ASAP.
3. **Joey Marks & his crew**

   We see them arrive several minutes after Veronica has already entered the bank.
4. **Harry Bosch & Jerry Edgar**

   Our heroes arrive last, having been elsewhere on a stakeout.

Each of these groups knows that Veronica's dead husband Tony has a safety deposit box at this bank containing millions of dollars that he embezzled from Joey Marks. However, Tony has assets at **six different banks** (revealed by the probate court's public announcement), so each of the parties must first figure out which bank is the right one before they can burn rubber to get there.

So now let's consider how each group knows which bank is the right one. In the order that's easiest to explain:

- **Bosch & Edgar**

  They have surveillance photos of Tony & his girlfriend. They compare the information in the probate court's announcement with those photos to figure out which bank has the loot.
- **Veronica Allen**

  I see two possibilities: maybe her husband shared the info with her during the period when he was embezzling from Marks but before he decided to run off with his girlfriend. Or Veronica discovered it while she was taking the aforementioned surveillance photos. For all we know, identifying the right bank was one of her goals for the surveillance.

  <sup>I think we know she took the photos herself -- it might be mentioned in ep. 6 or 7, but in any case we can reason that she wouldn't have Nash do it because the photos are part of her plan to frame Nash as the sole murderer of her husband. And he does seem surprised by their existence when he discovers them by accident.</sup>
- **Nash & his crew**

  It's possible Veronica told him while they were conspiring which bank had the loot. I'm skeptical of that, since it was clearly her plan all along to betray & frame Nash, but perhaps she figured that Nash would be in prison and thus unable to cause her any trouble when claiming the money.

  But we don't have to resort to that explanation, because Nash is in possession of those surveillance photos (Bosch & Edgar just have snapshots of them on a phone), and so he could have identified the correct bank the same way Bosch & Edgar did. And Jerry Edgar mentions that the court's ruling was issued an hour before the electronic announcement that tips off him & Bosch, so maybe Nash or one of his crew was playing the early bird by being present in the courtroom, giving Nash & co an hour to figure it out.
- **Joey Marks & his crew**

  This is my question: how did Marks know? Since I don't have an answer, let's *rule out* possible sources of his knowledge:

  Marks did figure out that Tony had been embezzling from him (which is why they had a loud argument). But it's hard to imagine that Tony would tell Marks which bank has the loot, *unless* he was also going to actually turn over the money to square things between them.

  Certainly Veronica isn't going to tell him, since it's her plan to run off with all the money. Neither would Nash, since he believes the plan is that he and Veronica will run off together with the money (*maybe* after paying Nash's accomplices for their help in doing the murder). Bosch & Edgar won't tell him because they are cops, not in the business of helping mobsters recover stolen money. Tony's girlfriend won't tell him because she and Tony were going to run off with the money they stole from him, and she's still afraid of him (she maybe even thinks he had Tony killed).

  Marks can't put it together himself the way Bosch & Edgar or Nash & co did, because he doesn't have (and presumably has never seen) the surveillance photos that Veronica took of Tony & his girlfriend.

  Furthermore, I think we can say that Marks did not merely guess the right bank. While he probably has the manpower to set up stakeouts at all six, the fact is that Marks himself is at the correct bank, which is unlikely given the odds.

  Notably, Marks sends a goon into the bank, but he doesn't see her in there (because she's already inside the secured safety deposit area). The goon tells Marks she's not there, and that someone drilled open a box because of probate. Marks responds, "It's her. We wait." I don't think this is proof that Marks was merely guessing as to the bank, because it doesn't explain how he himself is at the correct bank. Rather, I think this is merely Marks realizing that Veronica *beat them* to the bank, and thus that they must intercept her as she exits with the money rather than accosting her on her way in.

  As far as I can tell, these are all the possible sources of the information, and none of them is available to Marks.

So, how does Joey Marks & his crew know which of Tony Allen's six banks is the one that holds the cash Tony embezzled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Marks can't put it together himself the way Bosch & Edgar or Nash & co did, because he doesn't have (and presumably has never seen) the surveillance photos that Veronica took of Tony & his girlfriend.

That doesn't mean he wasn't carrying out his own surveillance but since Bosch SAYS that Marks figured it out the same way he did we have no option but to believe him.

Indeed, as we discover in Ep9, Marks had Layla investigated so it is possible that this included her visits to the bank.